# Error accessing a table generated by a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on some SQL exercises for class. For one query, I create a table within the FROM clause that I then refer to in my WHERE and SELECT clauses. As far as I know, this should not cause a problem because the SQL evaluation order is FROM -> WHERE -> SELECT. However, MS Access is giving me the following error:

"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Totals'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

Does anyone see the problem with my query?

Here are the available tables:

- Student (snum: integer, sname: string, major: string, level: string, age: integer)
- Class (cname: string, meets_at: string, room: string, fid: integer)
- Enrolled (snum: integer, cname: string)

Here is the exercise question:

1. Find the names of students enrolled in the maximum number of classes. The result should not contain any duplicates.

Here is my answer:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Totals.sname
FROM  ( SELECT      S.sname, COUNT(*) as Num
        FROM        Student S, Enrolled E, Class C
        WHERE       S.snum = E.snum AND E.cname = C.cname
        GROUP BY    S.snum, S.sname ) AS Totals
WHERE   Totals.Num = (SELECT MAX(Totals.Num) FROM Totals)
```

**Edit: William Burnham correctly pointed out that the problem lies in the WHERE clause. It seems that the subquery does not have access to the 'Totals' table. Is this a limitation of SQL (or perhaps MS Access's version of SQL), or is there a way to access the 'Totals' table from a subquery in the WHERE clause?**

Comment: I see one obvious issue:  You are using implicit joins.  You should only use commas in the `FROM` clause when you intend `CROSS JOIN` -- and then only because MS Access doesn't support the `CROSS JOIN` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We have not officially been taught the 'JOIN' keyword in our class yet, but I do agree that its usage would be more appropriate here. Unfortunately, switching to 'JOIN's does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try something like this:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM  Student S join Enrolled e on S.snum=e.snum
GROUP BY S.sname
HAVING COUNT s.snum= MAX(SELECT COUNT(e1.snum)
                         FROM Enrolled e1 join Class c on e1.cname=c.cname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution, but this doesn't explain why mine isn't working.

Comment: Does the output tell you which line your query fails on? It probably doesn't like WHERE   Totals.Num = (SELECT MAX(Totals.Num) FROM Totals) because the part where you want to get max totals num doesn't know (can't see) where it's supposed to get that information from. The having count bit from the answer above does the same thing you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Although the output does not say which line is failing, I am now certain you are right about the WHERE clause. As soon as I replaced the subquery (SELECT MAX(Totals.Num) FROM Totals) with a constant, the query was accepted without errors. Now the question is this: How can I access the 'Totals' table in my subquery?

Comment: That was just what I was thinking yesterday, but as I wasn't sure enough to post it, I decided not to. Cool we all can learn something new ^^

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you can't make a subselect in the where clause like this. 
Try using this :

```
WITH Totals(sname, Num) as (
SELECT      S.sname, COUNT(*) as Num
        FROM        Student S
                    join Enrolled E on S.snum = E.snum
                    join Class C on E.cname = C.cname
        GROUP BY    S.sname
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.sname
                FROM  Totals t
WHERE   t.Num = (SELECT MAX(t1.Num) FROM Totals t1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that MS Access does not recognize the 'WITH' keyword. Thanks for the alternative though.